# Which of `nohup sudo <command>` and `sudo nohup <command>` is recommended and why?

Tags: command-line, sudo

Is there any difference between them at all, some special use case that would make one of them preferable over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if a command does not need `root` privileges, you do not run it as user `root`.

Always try and execute with the least privs. Imagine there is a bug in `<command>` that allows an attacker to inject code to be executed with the privileges of the user that called `<command>`.

INCORRECT: However, in this specific case, I think `nohup sudo <command>` will prevent hangups in `sudo`, NOT `<command>`. So I would go for `sudo nohup <command>`.

EDIT:
In fact, according to `man fork`, any signals of child processes are inherited by the parent process, this seems to affect `nohup` as well. Thanks to Stephen Kitt for mentionning this.

So you can happily run `nohup sudo <command>`.

EDIT: Actually, I created the following test case:

```
$ cat /tmp/test1.sh /tmp/test2.sh
#!/bin/sh

/tmp/test2.sh &
sleep 5

#!/bin/sh

echo "test"

kill -HUP $$
```

When I run `nohup /tmp/test1.sh` the output (stored in nohup.out) is:

```
test
```

This means that `kill -HUP $$` was intercepted by nohup.

Comment: That makes sense to me. So (looking at other readers) unless I will get another answer with some counterintuitive but in-some-way authoritative disproof, it will soon be my accepted answer.

Comment: ... Or proof. (Not just disproof.)

Comment: `nohup` ignores `SIGHUP` in all child processes, so `nohup sudo` will work fine too.

Comment: @Stphen, wow, nice, do you have a source for this ? I could find nothing regarding this in the man page ...

Comment: I gave an upvote once. But honestly written, I don't understand the example. What would happen if your original answer was correct?